# Is it possible to prove $\angle A = \angle J$ with vectors and dot product?

Tags: geometry

I'm reading Coxeter's Geometry Revisited. Here:

> [image]

I'm trying to check that $\angle A = \angle J$ with the the definition of dot product: $\langle a,b \rangle=|a||b|\cos \theta $ but I'm not sure if it is possible. I did the folowing:

$J=-C$ then:

$$\langle -C, -C-B \rangle = - \langle C, C+B \rangle =\cfrac{- \langle C, C+B \rangle}{|C||C+B||}=Cos \theta$$

I'm using unit vectors $A,B,C$, then:

$$Cos \theta=\cfrac{- \langle C, C \rangle- \langle C, B \rangle}{|C||C+B||}=\cfrac{-1-\langle C,B \rangle}{|C+B|}$$

So I guess that I should check the other cosine, this would give me:

$\langle C-A, A-B \rangle= \langle C-A, A \rangle + \langle C-A, -B \rangle = \langle C,A \rangle + \langle -A,A \rangle + \langle C,-B \rangle + \langle -A, -B \rangle \\ = \langle C,A \rangle - 1 - \langle C, B \rangle + \langle A,B \rangle  $

And then:

$$\cos \psi =\cfrac{\langle C,A \rangle - 1 - \langle C, B \rangle + \langle A,B \rangle}{|C-A||A-B|}$$

With this, I see they are not compatible for comparison. Can anything be done beyond this point to verify that $\angle A = \angle J$? I am using the dot product because it is the only notion I remember that can be used to *talk* about angles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it by complex numbers for convenient. Since they are equivalent to vectors, you may just translate this proof in language of vectors.
Suppose the circle is of radius $1$, with its center $0$. Each point stands for a complex number on the circle $|z|=1$.
Now let $$z_\delta=\frac{(C-J)(\overline{B-J})}{(C-A)(\overline{B-A})}$$
It's easy to see that if $z_\delta\in\mathbb{R}$, then $|\angle BAC|=|\angle BJC|$. Since the radius is $1$, we have $\bar{A}=1/A$, etc. So
\begin{align}
z_\delta&=\frac{(C-J)(1/B-1/J)}{(C-A)(1/B-1/A)}\\
&=\frac{A(C-J)(B-J)}{J(C-A)(B-A)}\\
\overline{z_\delta}&=\frac{(1/C-1/J)(B-J)}{(1/C-1/A)(B-A)}\\
&=\frac{A(C-J)(B-J)}{J(C-A)(B-A)}
\end{align}

Hence $z_\delta=\overline{z_\delta}$, $z_\delta\in\mathbb{R}$. Done.